# Python: How to end while True loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

How would I go about ending this while True loop, I want the loop to end at the marked location, but i tried both `break` and `continue`, both don't end the loop. It just keeps the script running and it pretty much just stays there, doing nothing.

```
class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
def log_message(self, format, *args):
    return
def do_GET(self):
    if self.path.startswith("/checkTransfer"):
        qs = {}
        path = self.path
        if '?' in self.path:
            qs = parse_qs(urlparse(self.path).query)
            print "Received Transfer Check request for transfer id: " + qs["transferID"][0]
            while True:
                if checkProgress(qs["transferID"][0]) == 1:
                    self.send_response(200)
                    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/json')
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write('{"status" : 1}')
                    print "Transfer Completed! Checking for downloads"
                    ******* break; *******
                ******* ^ This is where I need to end the loop *******
                elif checkProgress(qs["transferID"][0]) == 0:
                    self.send_response(200)
                    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/json')
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write('{"status" : 0}')
                    print "Incomplete Transfer, Waiting..."
                    time.sleep(3)
                elif checkProgress(qs["transferID"][0]) == 2:
                    self.send_response(200)
                    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/json')
                    self.end_headers()
                    print "Could Not Find Transfer, Could Be Removed"
                    self.wfile.write('{"status" : 2}')
                    break;
```

Comment: You have to modigy `qs` inside your loop, otherwise the `if` and `elif` will always have the same output.

Comment: @julienc how would i go about doing that? I honestly just started using python and build most of this script from parts of different tutorials.

Comment: @julienc is right, the `break` is probably never being executed.  Do you even see the "Transfer Completed" message?

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala yes, i do see the message in the terminal output.

Comment: Then we stand corrected, we shoul have seen that checkProgress clearly had results that don't depend on its argument.  I don't see why `break`doesn't work.

Comment: by "doing nothing" do you mean it's not even printing anything? if that is correct, then the problem might be that `checkProgress(qs["transferID"][0])` returns other number than expected.

Comment: I think you should add an 'else' condition

Comment: @deathApril he says he sees the message.  In that case `break` should work.  My best guess is that the break *did* work and the program got stuck somewhere else.  In fact it might not even be stuck, since this is obviously an HTTP server, the server will just be waiting for the next request.

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala the message could have been from previous call of `do_GET` unless confirmed otherwise by SalB

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements only expect values 0, 1 or 2. Even if you are 100% sure that are the only possible values, you should catch unexpected cases and raise an exception if that happens - regardless of whether or not that is cause of the never-ending script in this particular case, it is a potential loophole in your code:

```
while True:
    if
        ....
    else:
        raise Exception("Unexpected value: " + checkProgress(qs["transferID"][0]))
```

Comment: I know it outputs either 0, 1, or 2. the function checkProgress prints out either 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: it may print something else than what it returns.. my point being that you should do this regardless of what is your current problem

Answer (score 0):

Set your `while` condition to the opposite of the end you're trying to achieve.

```
>>> import random
>>> while random.randint(0, 10) != 7:
...     print "argh"
... 
argh
argh
argh
argh #it does eventually end, and rather quickly
>>>
```

In such a situation it might be prudent to assign the value to something as well, or to simply `return` the value you want once you achieve it. Since your `while` is in a function you can use `return` to break the while loop as well.

```
def resultificator(desired_outcome):
    result = None
    while result != desired_outcome:
        result = get_the_result()
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have to guess here.  I think your loop really is exiting with the break, but you didn't notice because the server just goes and waits for the next client request.  Put a debug message like `print "do_GET finished"` at the end of the function to see if this is happening.